# Stack Overflow Trends - is it only about questions?

Tags: discussion, trends

Does tool "Stack Overflow Trends" analyze only questions asked with particular tags?

Just curious:
for example tags [oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop) and [functional-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) were created more than 9 years ago, and I guess lot of questions already answered and that's why no new questions and no reflection in "Stack Overflow Trends" but it doesn't mean that `functional-programming` not in trend now...

Comment: I'd imagine that they're looking at number of questions for X period of time with Y tag, so that would explain skew with older questions in older tags.

Comment: I would say people are more likely to tag a particular language / tool rather than the generic "OOP" or "functional-programming". Example: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=scala%2Cfunctional-programming%2Chaskell%2Cr

Comment: These kind of statistics are based on questionable data.  The only thing you *really* know is what kind of programming tasks and tools give programmers the most problems.  Popularity is a secondary factor that is about impossible to unravel from the data.  Imagine a source control product that everybody intuitively understands and never hassles a programmer, it will never compete well with [git] :)

Comment: I'm also a bit unclear by what you mean with "only questions".  Tags can only exist on questions.  What are you trying to get at?

Comment: @Makoto Yes, only question has tag. But trend it's what people looking for, what interesting and maybe (I don't know) SO have stats about search requests... or stats about found answers/questions/tags...

Answer (score 5):

From the blog post [Introducing Stack Overflow Trends](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/09/introducing-stack-overflow-trends/) (emphasis added):

> Today, we’re introducing the [Stack Overflow Trends tool](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=trends&utm_content=blog-link) to track interest in programming languages and technologies, **based on the number of Stack Overflow questions asked per month**.

So yes, it is based on the number of questions asked. No, this is not a perfect indicator of the popularity of a particular technology. It's really only measuring *what people are asking about on Stack Overflow*, which probably has a pretty strong correlation with what people are using, but no measure is perfect. (You might get a better correlation if you looked at Google searches, or Stack Overflow *views*, as the Stack Overflow data team does in [recent blog posts](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/06/incredible-growth-python/), but questions asked is probably a pretty good surrogate.)

The low occurrence of [oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop) and [functional-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) questions probably has more to do with the fact that people just don't use some generic tags as much as language tags than with the popularity of those paradigms. (I don't see much use of the [procedural-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedural-programming) tag at all.) It's probably more meaningful to compare activity in specific OOP and functional programming language tags than in those two generic tags themselves.